# Zip two EitherT[Future, _, _] in parallel with cats

Tags: scala, scala-cats

Regular futures in scala provide the `zip` operator. It combines their values when both succeed and runs them in parallel.
Is there something similar in cats when having two `EitherT[Future, _, _]`.

---

```
val a: EitherT[Future, String, Int] = EitherT.right(10)
val b: EitherT[Future, String, Int] = EitherT.right(20)
val sum: EitherT[Future, String, Int] = for ((a, b) <- a zip b) yield a + b
```

I would expect `sum` to be a `Right(30)` when `a` and `b` are both `Right` values. Additionally, as with the `Future.zip` function, both futures should run in parallel:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you're looking for applicative `mapN`

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits._
import cats.data.EitherT
import cats.instances.future._
import cats.syntax.apply._

val a: EitherT[Future, String, Int] = EitherT.right(Future(10))
val b: EitherT[Future, String, Int] = EitherT.right(Future(20))

val sum: EitherT[Future, String, Int] = (a, b).mapN(_ + _) // EitherT(Future(Success(Right(30))))
```

Comment: Due to your answer I've just found `tupled` which is an equivalent of `zip` but for EitherT. But with this solution i'm faceing the issue that EitherT has no `withFilter` method. It does therefore not allow pattern matching in for-comprehension to destructure the tuple.

Comment: Fantastic! `.mapN((_,_))` to return their result if types of rights differ but left is the same